# JavaScript retorna null al acceder a un elemento dentro de un option con getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Tengo un select como este:

```
<select>
    <option value="light">
        <p id="p1">Claro</p>
    </option>
    <option value="dark">
        <p id="p2">Oscuro</p>
    </option>
</select>
```

Y un `array` con elementos como este:

```
const messages = ["Light", "Dark"];
```

Lo que pasa es que intento cambiar el `innerHTML` a los elementos `p` dentro de los `option` por cierto elemento del `array`:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = messages[0];
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = messages[1];
```

Todo bien con el array. El problema es que no me cambia el texto, y en la consola dice: `null is not an object`, lo que quiere decir que no encontró mi elemento dentro del `option`. No es error de carga del JavaScript, ya que tengo la costumbre de cargar JavaScript al final del body.

¿Alguien sabe cómo arreglar esto o al menos cómo cambiar un tramo de texto de un `option` en JavaScript?

Gracias de antemano y espero que me puedas ayudar. ¡Ten un lindo día (o noche)!

Comment: Los options no deben tener ningun elemento dentro mas que texto, busca otra forma de hacer lo que necesitas, algun plugin, select2 puede servirte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No intente cambiarlo uno por uno los option del select. Mejor capture el select y en una variable guarde el html que necesita cambiar o modificar de la siguiente manera:

```js
let messages = ["Light", "Dark"];

let opciones=document.querySelector("#selector"); 

let elhtml=`<option value="light"><p>${messages[0]}</p></option>
                    <option value="dark"><p>${messages[1]}</p></option>`;
                    
opciones.innerHTML=elhtml;
```

```html
<select id="selector">
        <option value="light"><p>Claro</p></option>
        <option value="dark"><p>Oscuro</p></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Intenté hacer algo muy similar y ya se reemplaza. ¡Ten un lindo día! :D